# ring shapes for L preview not working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Just testing the new developer preview and noticed that my existing ring drawables are not rendering properly. Instead of a ring it's a full circle. Is it a bug or has something changed or am I doing it wrong to begin with? Any possible solutions?

here's the code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
            <solid android:color="#ff5698fb"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Thanks!

**Update**

I've updated the shape as follows:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
            <solid android:color="#ff5698fb"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="5.5">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

which produces a ring by overlaying two circles. But the progress bar that I'm using it in doesn't work.
Here is the code for the progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressCircle"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="65"
                android:rotation="270"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_circle"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out? My code is pretty much the same as yours - basically a custom circular progress bar. Now when I call updateProgress(), it seems to have no effect and the progress stays at 100%. It was working fine in previous Android versions, but Android L preview doesn't like something about it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add `android:useLevel="true"` in the progress item. This didn't seem necessary in previous versions, but L wants it.

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="7.0"
        android:useLevel="true" >
        <solid android:color="#ff5698fb"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I haven't had a chance to work on my project for a few weeks but this is appreciated!

Comment: strange... but now my Background is not visible?! EDIT: had to put useLevel="false" for the background

Comment: can you please let me know what does "uselevel" attribute signify .Could not make sense from android doc

Comment: To be honest, I did not completely understand it either. Looking at the  [Drawable docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel%28int%29) the level "allows a drawable to vary its imagery based on a continuous controller, for example to show progress or volume level." So the level probably does different things based on the type of drawable you have. In our case it just sets a particular amount of the ring to be drawn. This does beg the question as to why this is not the default behavior and why we need to set it explicitly!

Answer (score 21):

### TL;DR: Explicitly set the value of `useLevel` for all ring shapes used in custom progress bars.

---

Kano's answer is the way to solve your problem. I'm complementing it to add general info about ring shapes in custom progress bars.

It seems as if the default value for `useLevel` has changed over the Android versions. Here is a piece on investigation related to it.

The following is a working implementation of a progress bar using a ring as a progress indicator, and another ring as the progress background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Progress background -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid
                android:color="#dae1e6"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Progress -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <!-- Rotation of the progress to start at the top-->
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="-90">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <solid
                    android:color="#61bcf9"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Using it as a `progressDrawable` in a `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_horizontal"
    android:progress="50"
    android:max="100"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

**Setting `useLevel=true` to the progress ring shape and `useLevel=false` in the background ring shape, gives the correct desired behavior for all Android versions:**

[image: Correct in both versions]

**Removing `useLevel` from the background shape:**

Pre 5.0 (left) | 5.0 (right)

[image: Incorrect in KitKat]
[image: Correct in Lollipop]

**Removing `useLevel` from the progress shape:**

Pre 5.0 (left) | 5.0 (right)

[image: Correct in KitKat]
[image: Incorrect in Lollipop]

---

So, as I understand, `useLevel` is used to indicate whether the shape is affected by the progress value. If it isn't (false), it'll be fully painted; if it is (true), it'll be painted as much as the progress value is.

To sum up, it seems that:

- `useLevel` is defaulted to `true` in **Android < 5.0**, causing the background ring to follow the progress value if `useLevel` is not set in its ring shape, thus making it hidden behind the progress indicator ring.
- `useLevel` is defaulted to `false` in **Android >= 5.0**, causing the progress indicator ring to be fully painted if `useLevel` is not set in its ring shape.

So, due to this inconsistency, it's better to explicitly set the value of `useLevel` to `true` in the shapes which depend on the progress, and to `false` in the ones that don't.

This behavior is based on my observations, I haven't found any source confirming it. [The official Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) are not very clear about it...

Comment: Finally. I didn't think there was a way to do this in Android 5.0. Thanks for this guide!

Comment: can you please let me know what does "uselevel" attribute signify .Could not make sense from android doc

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add some references in framework source code to confirm that useLevel is defaulted to true in Android API version < 21 (< 5.0) and defaulted to false in API version >= 21 (>= 5.0) as Christian García previously stated.

In android-20, file GradientDrawable.java, line 820-835:

```
if (shapeType == RING) {
    ....
    st.mUseLevelForShape = a.getBoolean(
                    com.android.internal.R.styleable.GradientDrawable_useLevel, true);
}
```

In android-21, file GradientDrawable.java, line 1028-1047:

```
if (state.mShape == RING) {
    ....
    state.mUseLevelForShape = a.getBoolean(
                    R.styleable.GradientDrawable_useLevel, state.mUseLevelForShape);
}
```