# Android progressbar spinning loading bar not working on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I have a loading screen which has a spinner progress bar, it is spinning on my android studio emulator, running on Nexus 6 23api. Furthermore, I have tried using my friend's Redmi 2 and the spinner is working. But the spinner remains static(not spinning) on my phone galaxy s5 android 5.0. Please help

**layout file for the progress bar**

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_bar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loading_mod_logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

**loading screen java code**

```
public class LoadingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar spinner;
private boolean registered = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);

    //spinner is loading bar at loading screen
    spinner=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

Comment: Seems problem with your phone. Try after restarting the device

Comment: thanks for the reply @VarunPuravankara, I tried restarting but the problem still arises. I have found the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593237/ring-shapes-for-l-preview-not-working/26533127#26533127 which they observed that android version have different default useLevel

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and after a long debugging session I found that the animations are turned off:

```
android.animation.ValueAnimator.sDurationScale == 0.0f
```

This can be mitigated via *Developer Options > Drawing > Animator duration scale*. Set it to anything other than "off" to increase from `0.0f`.

I know it's not the root cause of your problem, but hopefully it will help others.

Answer (score 5):

It happens mostly if your phone is in power saving mode.