# Different selector behavior on API 21 and API 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

What kind of sorcery is this?

Api 23:
[image: Api 23]

Api 21:
[image: Api 21]

I am trying to implement a custom checkbox selector. After a couple of hours of trying to figure out what is wrong with my code, I came to the conclusion that the selector is rendered differently on different api levels. The images above are from AS, but I experienced the same behavior on a real device.

Here is the code if you want to test it out:

```
<item
    android:state_checked="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:innerRadiusRatio="5"
                   android:shape="ring"
                   android:thickness="0dp"
                   android:useLevel="false">
                <solid
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="#08aa92"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:innerRadiusRatio="2"
                   android:shape="ring"
                   android:thickness="0dp"
                   android:useLevel="false">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#cccccc"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

My question is: How can I fix this?

edit 1: it's seems like it's related to [ring shapes for L preview not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593237/ring-shapes-for-l-preview-not-working) , but I didn't manage to make it work yet.

Comment: Does it reproduce only in preview or at the devices too? That previews are always buggy and you can't trust them.

Comment: as I wrote in the description, it is not working on the devices as well

Comment: I would start by getting rid of `android:width="1dp"` from `<solid>` (as that is [not documented](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#solid-element)).

Comment: @CommonsWare that doesn't change a thing, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I still don't know what's the problem with API 23, but I managed to fix this problem by changing the first selector item to:

```
        <item>
            <shape android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
                   android:shape="ring"
                   android:thickness="10dp"
                   android:useLevel="false">
                <solid android:width="1dp" 
                       android:color="#08aa92"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
```

Only the thickness and android:innerRadiusRatio changed.